# Merge two UIImageView with respect to content mode?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

Is it possible to merge two UIImageViews with respect of content mode ? I have two UIImageViews one is AspectFit and One is Aspect Fill when i blend both images it combines correctly but not with the exact content mode.[image]

Here is the code

```
 CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(fx_imageView.image.size.width,fx_imageView.image.size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );

    // Use existing opacity as is
    [fx_imageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];

    // Apply supplied opacity if applicable
    [broderImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  //  resultImage.image = result;
```